# Does cuda updates include base Cuda?

Tags: cuda

This may be straight forward but I need to make sure to keep my sanity, does the Cuda updates include previous releases of the same version,for example:

**Cuda 11.2** has 2 updates, if I install **Cuda 11.2 update 1**, will it install **Cuda 11.2** or should I first install **Cuda 11.2** and then **Cuda 11.2 update 1**, also if I install **Cuda 11.2 update 2** will it include the fixes introduced in **Cuda 11.2 update 1** or should install them both?

Comment: CUDA 11.2.2 (= CUDA 11.2 Update 2) and 11.2.1 are completely standalone versions. You do not need Cuda 11.2 as a preinstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "update" versions of CUDA 11.2 are full versions. e.g. if you download CUDA 11.2.1 or 11.2.2 you're downloading *all* of CUDA and don't have to also download 11.2. (You could also tell by looking at the download size: 2.8 GB,  similar to CUDA 11.2 itself.)

In the past, there were some patch-like updates, IIANM, but not these.